# Suitable method for scheduler not found with play 2.1.1

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to use Akka and the scheduler with Play! Framework 2.1.1 in java.
I already used it in Scala, with Play 2.1.0, but the imports are not all working.

My current imports:

```
import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.Logger;
import play.libs.*;
import utils.MongoUtil;
import play.libs.Akka;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.Props;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import jobs.*;

import models.User;

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration;

import com.mongodb.*;
```

My code:

```
            ActorRef cron = Akka.system().actorOf(new Props(Cron.class));
            Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
              Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
              Duration.create(24, TimeUnit.HOURS),
              cron,
              "tick"
            );
```

Stacktrace:

```
 error: no suitable method found for schedule(FiniteDuration,FiniteDuration,ActorRef,String)
[error]                 Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
[error]                                          ^
[error]     method Scheduler.schedule(FiniteDuration,FiniteDuration,Runnable,ExecutionContext) is not applicable
[error]       (actual argument ActorRef cannot be converted to Runnable by method invocation conversion)
[error]     method Scheduler.schedule(FiniteDuration,FiniteDuration,Function0<BoxedUnit>,ExecutionContext) is not applicable
[error]       (actual argument ActorRef cannot be converted to Function0<BoxedUnit> by method invocation conversion)
[error]     method Scheduler.schedule(FiniteDuration,FiniteDuration,ActorRef,Object,ExecutionContext) is not applicable
[error]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

I tried a lot of things that I found on internet but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: I really don't like when you're not automatically rediriged on last version of API doc …
I had to add  Akka.system().dispatcher() after the "tick".

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory:

```
[error] method Scheduler.schedule(FiniteDuration,FiniteDuration,Runnable,ExecutionContext) is not applicable
[error] (actual argument ActorRef cannot be converted to Runnable by method invocation conversion)
```

So, `ActorRef` is not a `Runnable`.

You must call schedule this way (well, not exactly THIS way, modify it for your program):

```
system.scheduler().schedule(Duration.create(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
new Runnable() {
 ...   
}
}, system.dispatcher());
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact, it was missing a system.dispatcher() at the end, the error wasn't that self-explanatory … Thanks anyway !